# Cohomology of the coned off space

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, cohomology

Let $X$ be a compact manifold with boundary $\partial X$ with $
\dim X\setminus \partial X=n$. Moreover, $X$ and $\partial X$ are both aspherical. Then what's the $H^n(X\cup_{\Sigma\subset \partial X} C(\Sigma))$, where each $\Sigma $ is a boundary component? By Lefschetz duality, $H^n(X,\partial X)=\mathbb Z$. I am trying to apply the (relative) Mayer–Vietoris sequence to $H^n(X,\partial X)$ and $H^n(X\cup_{\Sigma\subset \partial X} C(\Sigma))$ to deduce the $H^n(X\cup_{\Sigma\subset \partial X} C(\Sigma))=\mathbb Z$, but it seems it's not very successful so far. Is there an easy way/reference to show $H^n(X\cup_{\Sigma\subset \partial X} C(\Sigma))=\mathbb Z$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to need some more assumptions about your manifold if you want $H^n(X,\partial X)=\mathbb{Z}$ (think about connectedness and orientability).

In general (even without those assumptions), $H^n(X\cup_{\Sigma\subset \partial X} C(\Sigma))\cong H^n(X,\partial X)$ for $n>1$:

Using the long exact sequence of the pair, $H^n(X\cup_{\Sigma\subset \partial X} C(\Sigma))\cong H^n(X\cup_{\Sigma\subset \partial X} C(\Sigma), \cup v_i)$, where $v_i$ are the cone points. Then by homotopy equivalence, this is isomorphic to $H^n(X\cup_{\Sigma\subset \partial X} C(\Sigma),  \cup C(\Sigma))$. If they weren't already, let $C(\Sigma)$ be the closed cones, and now apply excision.

I leave what happens in the cases $n=0,1$ as an exercise.